Create and printing a linked list of int values of a given length in Java
First create the linked list, then print it, then measure its length:
// Simple linked list class
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

// Build a linked list of ints of a given length
public static ListNode buildLinkedList(int length) {
    ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode currNode = head;
    for (int i = 2; i <= length; i++) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        currNode.next = new ListNode(i);
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }
    return head;
}

// Calculate the length
static int getLinkedListLength(ListNode head, int length) {
    if (head == null) {
        return length;
    }
    length++;
    return getLinkedListLength(head.next, length);
}

// Print the linked list
public static void printLinkedList(ListNode node) {
    System.out.print("Linked list = [");

    while (node.next != null) {
        System.out.print(node.val + ", ");
        node = node.next;
    }
    System.out.print(node.val);
    System.out.print("]");
    System.out.println();
}

// Test code
ListNode node = LinkedLists.buildLinkedList(5);
printLinkedList(node);
System.out.println("Length: " + getLinkedListLength(node, 0));

I am currently using a paramter to calculate the length.   I tried to make it an optional parameter but that did not work.  In order for getLinkedListLength to work, the parameter must be initialized to zero.
Is there a better way to do this?
I am a C# developer and I am using Java as a learning language for code challenges.  This would be easy for me in C# but not in Java.

@SitherTsering That is an aggressively bad comment. Truly horrible advice. please retract it.

The LinkedList should be a class with nodes and a size value.  When a value is added, increment the size.  When you remove an element, decrement the size.  And have a getSize() method to return the current value.

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you are trying to ask whether you can avoid passing in the length parameter to getLinkedListLength()?
You could use function overloading for this:
static int getLinkedListLength(ListNode head) {
    return getLinkedListLength(head, 0);
}

private static int getLinkedListLength(ListNode head, int length) {
    if (head == null) {
        return length;
    }
    length++;
    return getLinkedListLength(head.next, length);
}

I'm not sure why you made getLinkedListLength() package-private in your code, but I have kept that here.
However, I would recommend that you use an iterative approach instead:
public static int getLinkedListLength(ListNode head) {
    int length = 0;
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        length++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return length;
}

(You could also just use the built in LinkedList class, but I understand that you're doing this as an exercise, and not to use in some other project.)
